# Find the length of the chord BD

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Two chords *AB* and *AC* are drown in a circle with diameter *AD*. Find the length of the chord *BD* when angle *BAC* = 60°, *BE* is perpindicular to *AC*, and *EC* = 3 *cm*

*NOTE*: answers can include surds

[image: figure A]

Apart from being not drawn to scale, the real figure will be much different, it seems

I have also calculated the length of *AE* to be sqrt(3), however I can not guarantee that it is correct

Comment: Is the length of the diameter given?

Comment: Note that $AE \neq \sqrt{3}$. There are multiples values that can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**
1. $DC \parallel BE$.
2. Angle between $BD$ and $AC$ is $30^\circ$.
3. Translate BD by DC which moves B to X and D to C. Then, $XC=DB$ and $XCE$ is a $30^\circ-60^\circ-90^\circ$ triangle with a base length of $3$.

Comment: According to this BD = 2 * sqrt(3), which is correct. However how did you work out Hint 1 and 2

Comment: By "work out" do you mean "how did you come up with those" or "why are those true"? For the former, 1) Because the answer is independent of everything else, figure out how to relate BD to EC. 2) Angle chasing is often helpful, esp right angles.

Comment: I wanted to ask how those are true

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Have you used that AD is the diameter? What is $\angle ACD$? What is $\angle ABD$?

Comment: Oh now I understand. Both of them are 90 degrees,  I guess. Didn't know that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

We'll extend BE to touch the circle in point X.
Then we'll draw BD.
Note that angle ABE is 30 degrees.
ABD is drawn in a semi-circle so ABD.is 90 degrees.
So EBD is 60 degrees
The arc BDC is 2^BAC which is 120 degrees.
And the arc DCX is 2^DBX which is 120 degrees.
So the arc BDC equals the arc DCX
And by removing the arc DC from both sides:
The arc BD equals the arc CX
So its cord BD equals the other's cord CX.
So we wanna find CX:
Note that AEB is a 30-60 right triangle
So AE is G and BE is G multiplied by the square root of three.
AC AND BX ARE INTERSECTING CORDS IN A CIRCLE
SO BE ^Ex =AE ^EC
SO
G MULTIPIED BY THE SQUARE ROOT OF THREE ^EX = 3G
The G goes with the G
So XE is three over the square root of three 
CEX IS A RIGHT TRIANGLE
SO XC =BD = The square root of twelve.

Comment: Can you please help me to know any program that rights math equations because I'm really bad with computers?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).